# Please help identify the LEGO set from this picture

Tags: set-identification

Got it from a bulk lot but lost pieces.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific set looks like it is from the "Lego Clone Wars Republic Gunship" set, due to the 3 cylinder like pieces.

Comment: Which set do you keep in mind, 7676? That one doesn't have pieces seen in the provided picture and using different stickers. Cylinder like pieces you are referring to are present on both versions.

Comment: No 7163 you posted a pic down below

Comment: That one isn't from Clone Wars.

Comment: Yes look at the clone troopers and the Droideka and super battle droids. Its in the picture that you posted and for a person who's loved star wars all their life im pretty sure i know what those are.

Answer (score 5):

This is part of [Republic Gunship (7163)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7163-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Identified by [Dark Red [BL] Cylinder Half 2 x 4 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6259&colorID=59&in=A), which is unique to this set.